# Spotify Follow Playlist

Tags: spotify

I'm embedding Spotify playlists onto a wordpress website. Embedding the playlists is simple; though I'm having trouble creating a "Follow Playlist" button. I've looked through the Spotify API docs here: 
[Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/follow-playlist/)

I requested the authorization, and got the OAuth Token.

Based on what I've read, I'd assume I'd need to create an html link target such as:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wanderlustfest/playlists/5ehqaKNCIjtIuwNOALskcK/followers
```

(which doesn't work)

or

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wanderlustfest/playlists/5ehqaKNCIjtIuwNOALskcK/followers" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer BQD2Wg3K3P1Hk3fisKSWWLERtPmqcfQ5-mwvthR61ebB9i2NOIVIi5rXwrsg1fMkFrXMfui_HG2n65cOR3fzAw0b5KWfmofVMSjbT3yiqEsKz8uNQg8grKpwB2jijF6wvv-RapahtgczV25ePR6S3lilnuSjKaIXbKCrQtrmq7ojkda9k1xbGv2O4B1lAoDU527xbnx6IejInIB6crhCSC7Hsq2jJsbzkgNVKu8vShWyxkuHkVtU-y8mgCRdEOVay_k" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"public\":true}"
```

(which I have no idea what to do with)

This is an example playlist that I'm trying to embed:
This is the example playlist that I'm trying to get the Follow code for:
[DJ Taz Rashid](https://open.spotify.com/user/wanderlustfest/playlist/5ehqaKNCIjtIuwNOALskcK)

Playlist Author: wanderlustfest

Playlist ID: 5ehqaKNCIjtIuwNOALskcK

If someone could help me figure out how to get this Spotify Follow Playlist feature working, I'd greatly appreciate it!!!

- Bob

Answer (score 2):

The request to the Web API fails because you are probably making a GET request, not providing an access token, nor a body, which is required by that specific endpoint. That's what the curl command is trying to show.

If you are having difficulties with this I recommend you to use one of [the wrappers](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/#wrappers) that will make it easier for you to use the Web API using your preferred programming language.

If you are familiar with Javascript you can see an example of a button to follow a playlist using the Web API [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/j1sqq4g0/). The relevant code:

```js
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wanderlustfest/playlists/5ehqaKNCIjtIuwNOALskcK/followers',
      headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + <your_access_token>
      },
      method: 'PUT',
      success: function() {
          // do something
      },
      dataType: 'html',
      error: function(e) {
          console.error(e);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I Know very little about javascript or it's implementation, but I'm willing to learn. So obviously I replace the <your_access_token> with my long OAuth Key: BQD2Wg3K3P1Hk3fisKSWWLERtPmqcfQ5-mwvthR...(etc etc) , Do I then simple paste that into my html editor on the post, or do I have to have use a different step in order to make it functional? Wrap it with a <Script> or <iframe> ?  THANKS!